# Limit pageviews from Google Analytics API to the last 30 minutes

Tags: google-analytics, api, analytics-api

I am trying to find a way to query Google Analytics through the API to get pageviews for the last 30 minutes.  Like they have available through the Google Analytics console, but I want to put it in an automated report.  Has anyone found a filter that does this?

I have been playing with the Google Analytics Query Explorer - http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

But I haven't found a way to filter for the last 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For data from the last 30 minutes, you have to use the [real time reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/).  Google Analytics defines real time as 30 minutes, so that would exactly match your requirements.   The real time API supports [querying rt:pageviews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/pagetracking#rt:pageviews) which is the specific metric you are looking for.